# Multiple domain on one wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 domains with different suffixes(.ir and .com) which will park on one host.
My site is created by Wordpress, so when I use domain pointer in directadmin the (.com ) domain redirect on (.ir) one and all links finish with (.ir).
Is there a way which allow me to have multiple domains on one host without redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, the address you want visitors to see in the browser is different from the address used in the core of WordPress.
Read the full article [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)

You can do this by adding domains as add-on domains on your host and using a redirect with `.htaccess` file to the index of your site without changing the domain in browsers.

I hope I could help you